# iOS Text label like Bubble

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I am trying to create a Bubble out the text with curved radius as shown in the pic below.

[image]

```
task = task;
    member_date = member_date;
    comments =comments;
    activity = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", [task capitalizedString]  , member_date , comments]];

    [activity addAttributes:@{
                              NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14],
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor],
                              }
                      range:NSMakeRange(0, task.length)];

    [activity addAttributes:@{
                              NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14],
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithRed:102.0f/255.0f green:102.0/255.0f blue:102.0/255.0f alpha:1],
                              }
                      range:NSMakeRange(task.length + 1, member_date.length)];

    [activity addAttributes:@{
                              NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14],
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0f/255.0f green:102.0/255.0f blue:102.0/255.0f alpha:1],
                              }
                      range:NSMakeRange(activity.string.length - comments.length, comments.length)];
    return activity;
```

Answer (score 3):

This I m achieving with following code

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 120, 30)];
[self.view addSubview:lbl];
[lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[lbl setText:@"3 Comments"];
[lbl.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
[lbl.layer setBorderWidth:1.5];
[lbl.layer setCornerRadius:15];
```

And I getout put as [image]

Hope I received your requirement

Comment: i need to only get the oval shape for comments part only. The Task Text will not have this around it.

Comment: Add the layer only to the neccessary texts

Comment: didnt get u. can u please elaborate

Comment: You might have n number of  labels in you view since you want bubble corner only for comments add layer only for it